# Is it correct to use the Reader monad in this turn-based game?

Tags: haskell, monads

I need to learn to use the Reader monad. (And also the Writer and State).

The game-contests I do always consists in global parameters that are valid throughout the Game. And a bunch of parameters that are valid only during one Turn.

I ended all the latest contests with lots and lots of functions that almost all had Game and Turn as input parameters.

After having read about the reader monad, I am thinking about having:

```
data Game = Game AllNeeded StrategicPositions AndGameRelatedStuffs
data Turn = Turn PlayersPositions AndTurnDependentStuffs
```

and for each loop when I receive turn dependent data, I plan to have a variable `Reader Game Turn`:

```
turnReader = Reader currentGame currentTurn
let actionToPerform = play turnReader
```

Do you think it's the good example of application for the Reader monad ?
Do you think I can/should go blindfold and learn to use the Reader monad in this context ? Or is there a more appropriate monad for this, like State ?

Comment: This is not opinion based as (a) the Reader monad has very precise semantics and (b) the actual question has a limited scope compared to the title. I'll edit the title to make that clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Reader` monad is used when you have an *immutable* state that you want to read in your computation.  Is basically like having an extra argument implicitly passed to all the monadic actions.

It seems like in your game you actually want to *change* something (i.e. turn, or state of the game). In this case a `State` monad may be easier to work with.

In order to use `Reader` you have to group all actions that depend on the state, execute them in the monad then *outside* the monad change the state and run a new monadic computation with the modified state etc. This sounds cumbersome.

Note that using `Reader` is actually similar to using `State`. Simply: the `put` operation (and derivatives) are disallowed. So you could start writing using `Reader` and if you encounter a place were you'd like to modify the state you know that it would probably be better to use `State`.
Or viceversa: start by using `State` and if you end up never modifying the state replace it with `Reader`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems reasonable to have something like `StateT Turn (ReaderT Game IO)`, assuming `Turn` value changes every turn and `Game` doesn't. You'll need to read up on monad transformers for this (I personally like ["Monad Transformers Step by Step" (PDF)](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wh5a/personal/Transformers.pdf)).